# how to use months_between function using variables (PL-SQL)

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to use months_between function to calculate the age and assing it to a variable with INTO . However I am getting ora-00907 error all the time. What is wrong with my code that you can see below?Thanks.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION AGE_MOCKER (CUSTOMER_ID VARCHAR2)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   V_BIRTHDATE   DATE;
   V_AGE         NUMBER;
BEGIN

   V_AGE := 0;

   SELECT BIRTHDATE INTO V_BIRTHDATE  FROM CUSTOMER_ALL;

   SELECT FLOOR (
             MONTHS_BETWEEN (
                SYSDATE,
                  TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (V_BIRTHDATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 'DD.MM.YYYY')
                / 12)   INTO V_AGE
     FROM DUAL;


     IF V_AGE >30
     THEN
     RETURN 'YOU ARE SO OLD'
     ELSE
     RETURN 'YOU MAY LIVE'
     END IF;
END AGE_MOCKER;
```

Comment: Will be not bad to use the given CUSTOMER_ID when you select from customer_all and you can use floor and months_between direct in IF without select

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says, you're missing a right parenthesis:

```
   SELECT FLOOR (
             MONTHS_BETWEEN (
                SYSDATE,
                  TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (V_BIRTHDATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 'DD.MM.YYYY')
                / 12))   INTO V_AGE
---------------------^
```

But this is not right:

```
TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (V_BIRTHDATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 'DD.MM.YYYY')
```

`V_BIRTHDATE` is already a date, so converting it to a string and back to a date again is pointless.

And your first query:

```
   SELECT BIRTHDATE INTO V_AGE FROM CUSTOMER_ALL;
```

needs to be filtered by the passed_in `CUSTOMER_ID`; otherwise you'll get a too-many-rows exception if more than one customer exists. (You'll still get no-data-found if the passed ID doesn't exist). If that is also a column name in your table then it would be better to change your formal parameter name to be something different, e.g. using a prefix, to avoid scope issues.

You can also select straight from that table in a single step:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION AGE_MOCKER (P_CUSTOMER_ID VARCHAR2)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   V_AGE         NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT FLOOR (MONTHS_BETWEEN (SYSDATE, BIRTHDATE) / 12) INTO V_AGE
   FROM CUSTOMER_ALL
   WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = P_CUSTOMER_ID;
   IF V_AGE >30
   THEN
      RETURN 'YOU ARE SO OLD';
   ELSE
      RETURN 'YOU MAY LIVE';
   END IF;
END;
/
```

I've added missing semicolons on the `RETURN` calls too. This doesn't need a separate `V_BIRTHDATE` variable. You could also generate the string form the query and then return that; there are many ways to do most things...

Comment: I appreciate your helps and additional information you gave .It means a lot to me.